# Get MIN of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the MIN value from both tables (one return value).

Following mysql structure + data:

`table_master`

```
`ID` (Unique) | `Amount`

1 | 5.8
2 | 22.1
3 | 44.22
```

---

`table_variants`

```
`table_master_ID` | `Amount`

1 | 4.11
1 | 5.12
1 | 
1 |
2 | 9.22
3 |
```

---

With this query:

```
SELECT table_master.Amount, table_variants.Amount 
FROM table_master 
LEFT JOIN table_variants ON table_master.ID = table_variants.table_master_ID 
WHERE table_master.ID = 1
```

I get something like this:

```
5.8 | 4.11
5.8 | 
5.8 | 5.12
...
```

Now I need the MIN `Amount` value of both tables.
`ID` of `table_master` is unique, data in `table_variants` is optional.

How can I do this? I was trying `MIN()` with `CASE()` but without success.

Any hints?

TIA!

Comment: did u tried using `min` for both results in select statement..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(t.Amount) FROM
(SELECT Amount FROM table_master WHERE ID = 1
 UNION SELECT Amount FROM table_variants WHERE table_master_ID = 1) AS t
```

[MySQL UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT MIN(LEAST(table_master.Amount, table_variants.Amount))
FROM table_master 
LEFT JOIN table_variants ON table_master.ID = table_variants.table_master_ID 
WHERE table_master.ID = 1
```

[MySQL LEAST Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

Comment: Amount must be `CAST(AMOUNT as UNSIGNED)` and WHERE must be like that `AND Amount!='' `

Comment: CAST(AMOUNT as UNSIGNED) is possibly wrong way which may cause mistake in calculation, because it ignores non-integer part of number. What result do you get without it?

Comment: I receive an empty value '' OR a wrong value. without casting it as UNSIGNED. Datatype is `VARCHAR`... dont ask me why ^^

Comment: one more question: how to get the `ordernumber` of the MIN(Amount) in the same query?... i was trying to `Min(t.Amount), t.Ordernumber` but its the wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11563/discussion-between-frgtv10-and-ruben)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT MIN( CASE WHEN table_master.Amount<= table_variants.Amount AND table_variants.Amount IS NULL THEN table_master.Amount ELSE table_variants.Amount END) 
FROM table_master 
LEFT JOIN table_variants ON table_master.ID = table_variants.table_master_ID 
WHERE table_master.ID = 1
```

[This shows how it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8e2/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION to achieve this:

```
SELECT  "min from table1", MIN( Amount ) FROM table_master
UNION 
SELECT  "min from table2", MIN( Amount ) FROM table_variants
```

Comment: You forgot he's asking for the one with ID = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT LEAST(MIN(a.amount), MIN(b.value)) 
FROM table_master a, table_variants b
WHERE a.id = b.table_master_ID
AND a.id = 1;
```